# Numerical methods for ODE and consistent terminology

Tags: numeric, numerical-methods, ode, differential-equations

Hy everybody!

I am new to the subject "numerical methods for ODE". I read some basic literature but since most of the concepts and methods are new to me, I wanted to ask you, if you could give me feedback if I understand everything correctly (if there are wrong statements/definitions, would be great, if you could correct them :))

1. There are two numeric approaches for solving differential equations:

a)  Based on Taylor Series Approximation: Euler, Runge Kutta, etc. Goal: to have similar accuracy as with Taylor series but without calculating derivatives. Work-around was developed, where you only evaluate functions at certain points without calculating derivatives.

b)  Based on Interpolation Polynomials: Multi-Step Methods, Collocation methods: Make use of past information; no intermediate calculations (as in Runge-Kutta) . General idea: fit a polynomial using this past data + extrapolate from tn to tn+1

Stability: This graphic shows the stability for a specific test function:
[image]

Unfortunately, when it comes to stability, it depends on what ODE we want to solve. So there is no general way to say: Is this method stable for this ODE.  So we are creating a so called “model-problem” (see graphic) where we can compare different methods. --> is that correct?

Explicit Runge–Kutta methods are generally unsuitable for solving stiff systems because their region of absolute stability is small. Is there a specific reason why? Could anyone explain it in simple words?

Stiff systems have different time constants (fast, slow).

Implicit methods: Have much better stability properties than explicit methods. An explicit method can not be A-stable (everything on the left plane is stable). A-stable methods have no restriction on the step-length, they are very fast! Could anyone explain it in simple words why (some) Implicit methods are A-stable

Implicit methods are more computation intense – but probably you need fewer steps.

Regarding: “no restriction on the step-length”: Does that mean “even if the numeric solution is completely wrong (huge step-length), the system is stable?

Why have multi-step methods advantages compared to single-step methods when it comes to stiff-systems (and stability?)?

Comment: This looks good in general, but you will get better answers in the scientific computing (scicomp) or mathematics (math) forum of stackexchange. (You need more than Taylor for RK methods, Butcher trees etc., and you can equally well use Taylor expansions to compute multistep methods.)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the area of stability of Runge-Kutta methods.

You can write an explicit Runge Kutta method as follows:

Let d/dt(x) =Ax. Then Psi( tau ) = P( tau*A )x, where P is a polynomial, Psi is the phase flow and tau>0.
If you apply this theorem:

"The area of stability of polynomials is compact."

you see why explicit Runge-Kutta methods have smaller areas of stability. P(z) obviously converges to +/- infinity if z converges to +/- infinity.

Implicit Runge-Kutta methods on the other hand can be written as Psi(tau)=R(tau*A)x, where R is the quotient Q = P/Q of two polynomials, Psi is the phase flow and tau>0. Thats why their area of stability can be larger.